# htaccess help, removing a string from the URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, server-configuration

I am wondering, is it possible to remove index.php from an URL? Basically on some pages in a site I have this structure,

http://www.domain.com/index.php/members/register, but other pages I have URL structures like this, http://www.domain.com/category/products/id/5, I want to know is it possible with htaccess to remove the index.php and any attributed slashes when needed? How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. With this rule any requested `/index.php` will be removed:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /index\.php[/?\ ]
RewriteRule ^index\.php(/(.*))?$ /$2 [L,R=301]
```

But you should better use the proper URLs right from the start so that you application is serving documents whose links don’t contain the `/index.php`.

Answer (score 0):

### If you want to globally rewrite index.php/controller/action

This .htaccess configuration should do the trick:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This configuration checks on Apache whether the file/directory exists on disk or not (i.e. the request match a real resource on disk), and rewrite the request to [your front controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern) if needed.

So `http://www.domain.com/resources/image.png` should return the image resource.
And `http://www.domain.com/user/show/5` should transparently rewrite to `http://www.domain.com/index.php/user/show/5`

With this configuration, **you can remove all index.php references in your application URLs** and leave the rewriting to the web server.